# SQLite extract string from text in column

Tags: regex, string, sqlite, openstreetmap, spatialite

I have a Spatialite Database and I've imported OSM Data into this database.
With the following query I get all motorways:

```
SELECT * FROM lines 
    WHERE other_tags GLOB '*A [0-9]*'
    AND highway='motorway'
```

I use `GLOB '*A [0-9]*'` here, because in Germany every Autobahn begins with A, followed by a number (like A 73).

There is a column called `other_tags` with information about the motorway part:

```
"bdouble"=>"yes","hazmat"=>"designated","lanes"=>"2","maxspeed"=>"none","oneway"=>"yes","ref"=>"A 73","width"=>"7"
```

If you look closer there is the part `"ref"=>"A 73"`.

I want to extract the `A 73` as the name for the motorway.

How can I do this in sqlite?

Answer (score 4):

If the format doesn't change, that means that you can expect that the `other_tags` field is something like `%"ref"=>"A 73","width"=>"7"%`, then you can use `instr` and `substr` (note that 8 is the length of `"ref"=>"`):

```
SELECT substr(other_tags,
              instr(other_tags, '"ref"=>"') + 8,
              instr(other_tags, '","width"') - 8 - instr(other_tags, '"ref"=>"')) name
FROM lines 
WHERE other_tags GLOB '*A [0-9]*'
  AND highway='motorway'
```

The result will be

```
name
A 73
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with following condition..

1. `other_tags like A%`  -- Begin With 'A'.
2. `abs(substr(other_tags, 3,2)) <> 0.0` -- Substring from 3rd character, two character is number.
3. `length(other_tags) = 4` -- length of `other_tags` is 4

So here is how your query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM lines
WHERE other_tags LIKE 'A%'
  AND abs(substr(other_tags, 3,2)) <> 0.0
  AND length(other_tags) = 4
  AND highway = 'motorway'
```